# Calling Ant Macrodef from Gradle

Tags: ant, gradle, build.gradle, macrodef

I can't seem to find a way to list and/or call an Ant Macrodef from within my Gradle script. The Gradle User Guide [talks](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html) about Macrodefs but does not provide an example anywehere. Could anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

At the moment I import the Ant build by executing the ant.importBuild task. This works fine as the Ant targets show up as Gradle tasks. However, I am not able to list and/or call the Ant Macrodefs stated in the Ant build. Could anyone provide me the answer?

Comment: Does the solution work for you? If yes you may want to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `build.xml`

```
<project name="test">

    <macrodef name="sayHello">
        <attribute name="name"/>
        <sequential>
            <echo message="hello @{name}" />
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

</project>
```

and `build.gradle`

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'

task hello << {
      ant.sayHello(name: 'darling')
}
```

Let's test it

```
/cygdrive/c/temp/gradle>gradle hello
:hello
[ant:echo] hello darling

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.487 secs
```

Comment: Although this solution does not entirely solve my problem, this is the/a way to call Ant macrodefs within Gradle. The reason I couldn't find a way to call the macrodefs was that my macrodef name contains a few '-' characters, which Gradle can not cope with.

Comment: Do you know a way to list all loaded macrodefs?

Comment: @HELOX No, I didn't find a way to list them

Answer (score 2):

Ant allows macro names that do not fit into Groovy's identifier limitations.
If this is the case, explicit `invokeMethod` call can help.
Given:

```
<project name="test">

<macrodef name="sayHello-with-dashes">
    <attribute name="name"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo message="hello @{name}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

</project>
```

this will work

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'

task hello << {
  ant.invokeMethod('sayHello-with-dashes', [name: 'darling'])
}
```